# Typeorm - shared database

Tags: database, microservices, typeorm

I have multiple services and they use the same database
For this reason, I have to duplicate my entities across the services

How can I re-use **TypeORM** entities?

Answer (score 1):

Im in a very similar scenario right now. My approach has been, so far, generating a GitHub subdirectory `dataSource` where my migrations and models are located within "Service1", and then clone and link this new subdirectory into the new "Service2".

This link was very useful for doing that: https://ffimnsr.medium.com/make-sub-folder-a-git-submodule-7e4290d41ff6

Now both Services can read/write to the same database. Any change to files within `dataSource` from either service will reside in the subidrectory and will have to be commited directly on the subdirectory, so just take that in mind.

Still looking for what other alternatives I can find.

An additional alternative that worked fine for me was publishing the repository/service/project that originally contained the Entities as a npm package, and then just use those entities (and even the migrations) directly from the npm package.

For the TypeORM dataSource/Connection config I just pulled the corresponding entities and migrations like this:

```
entities: ['node_modules/@my-npm-package/dist/models/**/**.entity.js']
```

```
migrations:  ['node_modules/@my-npm-package/dist/migration/**.js'],
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).